# C# graphics drawlines draws broken lines

Tags: c#, graphics, antialiasing

I am drawing ECG graphs using C# Graphics. I draw the curve using drawlines method. however line joints look broken. I tried all available options of smoothing mode and capstyle, none helps. here is [sample graph1](http://eng.harran.edu.tr/~msuzer/snapshot.png) and [sample graph2](http://eng.harran.edu.tr/~msuzer/snapshot2.png)

code is below:

```
private void DrawCurve(Graphics g, cPoint[] data)
{
    List<Point> ps = new List<Point>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        int x = data[i].x;
        int y = data[i].y;

        if (x > 0 && x < (Width))
        {
            ps.Add(new Point(x, y));
        }
        else if (x > Width)
        {
            using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Yellow))
            {
                if (ps.Count > 0)
                {
                    g.DrawLines(p, ps.ToArray());
                    ps.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks entirely normal to me.  Nothing like a noisy signal to demonstrate how poor the resolution of standard monitors are.  Fixing it requires spending the kind of money on hardware that's common in the medical business, sets you back a couple of grand.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid broken lines especially when the lines are drawn at sharp angles you need to choose the right values for these Properties:

```
p.MiterLimit = p.Width * 1.25f;
p.LineJoin = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineJoin.Round;
```

The [MiterLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.pen.miterlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a default of 10f, which is way to big for thin lines!
The LineJoin also has a default (Miter) that does not help.

You should also **experiment** a little with the `MiterLimit` value (keep in the range of the Pen's width) and maybe also with your `Pen`'s width itself; do **note** that `Pen.Width` is a `float` so you could raise it to 1.25 or so..

If you are actually talking about the smudgy look at some spots, this is due to anti-aliasing; usually a good thing, but for crisper lines turn it off for your Graphics object:

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode =  System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None
```

The `LineCaps` are only for the start- and the end-point of the lines-sequence, so they do not matter much for your graph.

Comment: Thank you @TaW for your prompt answer, I learned much from your answer, though none of the advices fix my problem except turning off anti-aliasing. I tried anti-aliasing off already but I am not happy with the result. I tried almost any combination of MiterLimit value and LineJoin style, still no help. It does not improve it in any way, and I left with no clue about what is going on there.

Comment: Hans has made a good point. Maybe your problem is indeed that you are looking the raster graphic's resolution and therefor see its limits. Actually Retina displays are getting affordable, but how many will you need?! Have you also tried to bring up the Pen.Width a little? Finally: Do you think you could improve your example image in a paint program so we can see how you want it to look?

Comment: I added another image (sorry, that is the best I can get), in which the curve is formed of many short vertical lines. You may see that joint of two successive vertical lines is kind of broken or cracked (well, maybe I can't find the correct word to describe it). I want to make adjacent line pieces look connected. I don't think this is an issue with display hardware. I played with Pen.Width a little, it did not do the trick, however it is so strange that when I increased the Pen.Width to 2.0 the curve gets blurred so as if the display is out of focus.

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing short lines. This is why you are getting that result. Instead of *DrawLines()*, try to use [DrawCurve()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ak09y3z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
g.DrawCurve(p, ps.ToArray());
```

Comment: Good advice for the hand-drawn red lines but for ECG graphs I think I would rather not draw _invented_ curves..